# The law of large number of minimum i.i.d variables random

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Note that from https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-21/issue-3/Limit-of-the-Smallest-Eigenvalue-of-a-Large-Dimensional-Sample/10.1214/aop/1176989118.full

Let $\{x_{ij}\;|\;i,j=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a double array of i. i.  d. random variables and let $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, $\beta\ge 0$ and $M>0$ be constants. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \max_{i\le Mn^\beta}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{ij}-m}{n^\alpha}\right|\to 0\ a.s.\ (n\to\infty)
\iff
E|x_{11}|^{\frac{1+\beta}{\alpha}}< \infty\ \&
\  m=\begin{cases}\displaystyle
E x_{11},&(\alpha\le 1),\\
\displaystyle\text{any},&(\alpha>1).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Suppose that $n,p\to\infty$ with $p/n\to c>0$. I am confuse that how to derive law large number from i. i. d $x_j,x_{ij}\sim N_p(0,1)$. I mean I want to derive
\begin{align*}
\min_{i\le p}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{ij}^2}{n}\to 1\; a.s.\;\text{and}\;\min_{i\le p}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_jx_{ij}}{n}\to 0\; a.s.
\end{align*}

What is $M$ to derive the above convergence?

Comment: The assertion is intended to hold for *any* positive $M.$  What, then, does your question mean?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Actually, I am confused to define $M$  to get $$\min_{i\le p}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_{ij}^2}{n}\to 1\;a.s.$$. In the paper that I shared, $M$ should positive constant. If I define $M=p/n$, it is false because $p,n\to \infty$. So, what should I define $M$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n/n \to c$$ you also have $p_n = O(n)$, and there is some $M$ such that $p_n \leq Mn$ for all $n$.

Thus you can use

$$\begin{align*} \exists M : \Bigl[
 \min_{i\le p_n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{y_{ij} -m}{n} \leq  \overbrace{ \max_{i\le Mn^\beta}\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{y_{ij}-m}{n^\alpha}\right|\to 0\ a.s.\ (n\to\infty)}^{\text{holds for any $M>0$}} \Bigr]
\end{align*}$$

with $y_{ij} = x_{ij}^2$, $\beta = 1$ and $\alpha = 1$.

You don't need to know $M$. All you need to know is that there exists some $M$ for which the inequality holds. The convergence holds for any $M$.

Comment: This answer solves the first case, but I do not see how to apply it to $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_jx_{ij}}{n}$. But, your case using a minimum instead of maximum and dividing by $n$ instead of $n^{0.5}$ makes it a much less strong case and you can proof that the limit is $0$ by using the law of large numbers stating that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} x_{ij}$ has the limit $0$ for each individual $j$ and so it is certainly true as well for the minimum. The complication is that you have $x_j \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} x_{ij}$, I am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: Your expression is equivalent to a product distribution of $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ $$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_jx_{ij}}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}XY$$ The distribution of the product $XY$ [is a modified Bessel function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Independent_central-normal_distributions). The increase of ${n}$ makes that the density converges pointwise to zero everywhere except at $XY=0$ so you have a.s. convergence to zero. This means at least convergence in probability. I am not sure how to proof a.s. convergence.